# Inverse function of $f(x) = x^2 \log x$, $x > 1$?

Tags: reference-request, special-functions, inverse-function

Is there a known expression/name for this function?

Comment: Locally? There is no global inverse since $f$ is not injective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse of the function $f(x)=x^2 \log x, \; x>1$ is given by $$f^{-1}(x)=\frac{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{W(2 x)}},$$
where $W$ is the Lambert $W$-function.

Comment: Yes, $y^2 \log y^2 = 2 x$.